# In Vue cli project, where to place Laravel api app and how to call api in vue js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vue-cli

vue app is inside :    `C:\xampp\htdocs\booking`

Laravel api is inside : `C:\xampp\htdocs\booking-api`

FYI : vue app is working on **http://localhost:8080**

If the folder structure is like above, then app works fine i can call the api like this,

```
axios.get('http://localhost/booking-api/public/Rooms').then((response)=>this.items = response.data);
```

But I want `booking-api` folder inside `booking` folder. If I place it and if I call the api like below,

```
axios.get('/booking-api/public/Rooms').then((response)=>this.items = response.data);
```

It wont work and the console window is like this,

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/booking-api/public/Rooms
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

So, how can I place `api` project inside `vue` app and how to call the api from vue.

Comment: When you placed `booking-api` inside `booking` did you re-serve your server or not ?

Comment: @Maraboc,  working on it

Comment: Can't you just setup two virtual hosts each one with a named domain? Much much easier that way.

Comment: @Maraboc , after re-serving no luck

Comment: Try `php artisan cache:clear` and then re-serve again !

Comment: @apokryfos, if i create two virtual host with i cant able to use development server. so im making virtual host for api and access it from vue cli dev server. its temporary but ur idea helped.

Comment: @arun you will need to use a proper webserver and not the built-in php server if you want to set up virtual hosts. I'm only suggesting it because it will probably be a closer match to the setup of the production server as well
 and that would make testing easier.

Comment: @apokryfos , yeah understand

Comment: @Maraboc, FYI: `http://localhost/booking/booking-api/public/Rooms` this link returns json. but not this link `http://localhost:8080/booking-api/public/Rooms`

Comment: If you are inside a blade template you can use `{{ URL::to('/') }}/Rooms`

Comment: Write the vue elements in the laravel blade views. It is better than keeping two separate apps for API and the front end.

Comment: The reason why you can't call the API using `http://localhost:8080/booking-api/public/Rooms` is because it's served from localhost:8080, and I think that is not served by apache. No apache = no php = no laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i guess you used `vue.js` webpack build in your project.
Steps.

1. serve your `vue.js` projet using `npm run dev`
2. for `npm run dev` the default server for vue would be `localhost:8080`

Now your api-part

1. It doesn't matter where you put it. Install `laravel` using follow normal procedures;serve it using `php artisan serve`. 
   it will run normally on `127.0.0.1` or `localhost:8000`.
2. Lets assume: a script on a sample component  `axios.post('localhost:8000/api/postData',data).then((response) => 
   {//do something here}`

While posting here you should take care of the Cross Origin Resource Sharing, or may be csrf issues if you remove the existing component.